# remote server connection error while trying to connect postgresql server to power bi via ODBC server

Tags: postgresql, powerbi, odbc, remote-server

hello all i have installed ODBC driver to connect remote server´s database (postgresql) and after providing input of server name, database name, port, ID and password the test is failing...what to do???thanks

Comment: Without an error message it's nearly impossible to answer your question. It can be anything between a wrong host address and an alien invasion :)

Comment: if all input data is right and it fails without an error message (or with a timeout), check the firewall settings

Comment: the error message is "Details: "ODBC: ERROR [08001] could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
 Is the server running on host "**********" (**********) and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port ****?
"

Comment: Assuming that port number and hostname are correct, you can start by a) is the server up and running? b) is the server set to accept remote connections (`listen_addresses =*` )? c) is the firewall blocking connection attempts from the client?

Comment: a) yes b) yes c) i do not know how and what to check on firewall settings?

Comment: it will depend on the OS of your server. I use `firewall-cmd`: https://firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewall-cmd.html